# Effect of sudo on the performance of `gsettings set` command

Tags: sudo, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gsettings

I wrote the following script to enable certain GNOME shell extensions. I noticed that this script will return different behaviours when it is executed as "sudo" as compared to "ordinary user".

**As Ordinary User:** From terminal, after issuing `python3.6 scriptname.py`, this script will make the necessary settings changes, the effects will be visible, and the changes will be registered in the "dconf Editor", i.e. its /org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions tab will contain the values of GS_ENABLED_EXTENSIONS. When I manually re-issued the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, the enabled extensions remains in effect.

**As sudo:** First, I used the dconf Editor to reset /org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions to it's original value. Next, from the terminal, after issuing `sudo python3.6 scriptname.py`, the script's setting will take effect and the setting changes will be visible. However, when I re-opened the dconf Editor, i.e. /org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions, I noticed the values of  GS_ENABLED_EXTENSIONS will not appear there. In fact, it's original value still appears. Now, when I manually re-issued the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, the enabled extensions settings by the script will be visually lost, and visually the GNOME shell will show the extensions in the dconf Editor, i.e. it's original values.

**Question:** Why does the `gsettings set` command behave differently when it is executed as `sudo` as compared to an "ordinary user"? Is there a way for sudo to return the same behavior as an ordinary user?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import ast
import time
from subprocess import run, PIPE


INSTALLED_GSEXTENSIONS = ['user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
                          'workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']


def set_gs_enabled_extensions():
    global GS_ENABLED_EXTENSIONS, CMD

    print( '\nEnabling GNOME shell extensions...' )
    #Commands
    get_enabled_extensions = [ 'gsettings', 'get', 'org.gnome.shell', 'enabled-extensions' ]
    set_enabled_extensions = [ 'gsettings', 'set', 'org.gnome.shell', 'enabled-extensions' ]

    #Get existing GS enabled extensions (if any).
    enabled_extensions = run( get_enabled_extensions, stdout=PIPE ).stdout.decode().rstrip()
    GS_ENABLED_EXTENSIONS = set( ast.literal_eval( enabled_extensions ) )

    #Enable existing and installed GS extensions.
    GS_ENABLED_EXTENSIONS.update( INSTALLED_GSEXTENSIONS )
    begin=' '.join( set_enabled_extensions )
    CMD=f'{begin} "{[*GS_ENABLED_EXTENSIONS,]}"'
    print( '\nCMD=', CMD )
    run( CMD , shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout )
    print( 'Enabling GNOME shell extensions... Done' )


def restart_gnome_shell():
    print( '\nRestarting GNOME shell ...' )
    cmd = 'xdotool key "Alt+F2+r" && sleep 0.5 && xdotool key "Return"'
    run( cmd, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout )
    print( '\Restarting GNOME shell ... Done.' )


def main():
    set_gs_enabled_extensions()
    restart_gnome_shell()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: The the environment (i.e. available variables) is important for `gsettings` as well, and varies when using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dconf settings are stored in a database on a per-user basis. When you run a command with `sudo`, the $USER is `root`, not anymore your own user. `gsettings` will therefore act on the dconf database of the `root` user if it exists, rather than on the dconf database of a specific user.

An in depth guide for system administrators about dconf is available on [the gnome wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators). It suggests that the database on which dconf acts can be set by the DCONF_PROFILE environment variable.

Comment: Can you also explain what happens when Alt+F2+r+Return is executed? Btw do you know what is "_the schema vendor override system as part of GSettings_' mentioned in the link that you had provided?

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find the "dconf database of the root user"?